# Create a column in pyspark dataframe based on the columns from other dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I have 3 pyspark data frames (df_main, df_xyz, df_cvb) where df_main is the driver data frame where a column(new_col) needs to be created based on the conditions

```
l = [(1,’XYZ', '324 NW', ‘VA’), (2,’XYZ, '323 NW', ‘VA’), (3,‘CVB’, '314 NW', ‘VA’)]
df_main = spark.createDataFrame(l, (‘ID’, ’Name', 'Address', 'State')) 
ID   Name   Address State
1     XYZ   324 NW  VA
2     XYZ   323 NW  VA
3     CVB   314 NW  VA


l = [(1 ,10, ‘A’), (2,20, ‘B’), (4, 120, ‘C’)]
df_xyz = spark.createDataFrame(l, (‘ID’, 'col1', 'col2')) 
ID    col1     col2
1     10       A
2     20       B
4     120      C


l =  [(1 ,56), (2,45), (3,12)]
df_cvb = spark.createDataFrame(l, (‘ID’, ‘col3’)) 
ID    col3  
1     56     
2     45     
3     12
```

Create a column “new_col” in df_main data frame as.
If Name = ‘XYZ’, get col1 value from df_xyz on ID col
If Name = ‘CVB’, get col3 value from df_cvb on ID col

So my expected output df_main data frame should look like below

```
ID   Name    Address  State     new_col
1     XYZ    324 NW   VA        10
2     XYZ    323 NW   VA        20
3     CVB    314 NW   VA        12
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [(1,'XYZ', '324 NW', 'VA'), (2,'XYZ', '323 NW', 'VA'), (3,'CVB', '314 NW', 'VA')]
df_main = spark.createDataFrame(l, ('ID', 'Name', 'Address', 'State')) 

l = [(1 ,10, 'A'), (2,20, 'B'), (4, 120, 'C')]
df_xyz = spark.createDataFrame(l, ('ID', 'col1', 'col2')) 
 df_xyz = df_xyz.select( df_xyz['ID'],df_xyz['col1'].alias('new_col'), lit("XYZ").alias("table") )

l =  [(1 ,56), (2,45), (3,12)]
df_cvb = spark.createDataFrame(l, ('ID', 'col3')) 
df_cvb = df_cvb.select( df_cvb['ID'],df_cvb['col3'].alias('new_col') , lit("CVB").alias( "table"))
cond = [ df_cvb['ID'] == df_main['ID'], df_cvb['table'] == df_main['Name']]
condxyz = [ df_xyz['ID'] == df_main['ID'], df_xyz['table'] == df_main['Name']]

df_result = df_main.join( df_cvb, cond, "inner").union(df_main.join( df_xyz,condxyz,"inner"))
```